# "Undefined Control Sequence"-Error when using Biblatex with apa style

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

Today I started to try biblatex for the first time in my `apa6.cls` document:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{vonDavier2011}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I just copied the content of the .bib file from the `bibliography.bib` of the `apa6.cls` example file for some testing so the .bib content is alright.

This works as long as I load `biblatex` only with `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`. But when I additionally specify apa citation style like in the example above, I get the Error

[image: Undefined Control Sequence]

right after the `\printbibliography` line.

I have to mention that I am not an advanced latex or even biblatex user. F. e. I just changed the output profile from bibtex to biber and don't know what is meant with "biber %" I read about in other topics. Should I include that anywhere?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error lies in declaring the `ngerman` option in the `\documentclass` line.

Here's what happens. When `babel` is loaded, it is passed all the global options, so `ngerman`; then it examines the local options, `english` and `ngerman`; since the latter has already been loaded, it has no effect and the main language becomes English.

You can check this by adding `\languagename` after `\begin{document}`, which will print “english”.

Solution: don't use `ngerman` in `\documentclass` or use both. If you have `babel` version 3.9, you can solve also by issuing

```
\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
```

and, in this case, the `ngerman` option in `\documentclass` will do no damage.

Comment: Ok, I removed it in the document options and that worked. The language command still says "ngerman" is the document language, which is good. Nevertheless I still get a "package biblatex warning macro 'name:apa:first-last' undefined" Warning... do you might have any idea on that also?

Comment: @entne I get no warning, sorry.